# Is persistence responsibility in an object violating SRP?

Tags: c#, oop, single-responsibility-principle

I struggle with justifying whether this is violating SRP or not. The Employee class simply represents an employee in the system.

```
class Employee
{
  int id;
  string name;
  Date startDate;
  int departmentCode;


  void UpdateEmployeeInformation(some arguments) //updates the data in DB

  void DaysInTheCompany() //calculates now - startDate  difference

}
```

According to what I can read, it does violate SRP, but I am not sure why (I assume it is because the Update method is a different responsibility than just holding the data?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. What's so difficult to understand about that? The object represents a snapshot state of an Employee, but it should not be responsible for loading/saving that data because it's an orthogonal concern - if you think that's okay, then why isn't the `class Employee` also responsible for displaying that data on-screen (both as a web-page and a 1980s mainframe terminal compatible view), sending payroll bank instructions via ACH, printing the employee's identity badge by PostScript, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  it is violating the SRP.

The responsibility of Employee is to hold employee information, maybe some calculations, like DaysInTheCompany, but accessing a DB of File is not part of his responsibility.

Your example is one of the easiest to identify.

This post was useful to me.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/587404/Understand-Single-Responsibility-and-Interface-Seg

Your Employee class is just a container, You will populate this container in your business layer and pass it to the Data layer.

I use a Service class, (EmployeeService), this class receives the Employee object and update the information in the database.

In this link, you can see some ideas.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156481/how-should-i-encapsulate-database-access

Comment: So what would be the solution for this? How should I implement updating that does not violate SRP? The class still needs to pass its changed data somewhere

Comment: One solution is to implement Repository Pattern or use an EmployeeService. This service will receive an Employee object and update the database information.

Answer (score -2):

No it does not, is it a good approach actually. An object can internally encapsulate a db connection which will use to do its job. The responsibility of the object is to make the update, which usually means to update the data in the db.

Comment: Well, all the books actually disagree with you, stating that this is the typical example of SRP violation, as the persistence is mixed with application logic. You would need to change the object when the DAL changes, for example.

Comment: If the Employee object does not store the data directly to the db then what is his "single" responsibility?

Comment: Basically I would say that he should not care at the persistence at all. His responsibility is to take hold the data and perform some operations with it.

Comment: So again it does two jobs:stores data in memory and performs some other operations. So again there is a violation of SRP. What's the difference by storing in db and doing some other operations? Also it is a good practice objects to me immutable and stateless.

Comment: Not really, the class represents an Employee, and therefore it stores its data and can perform operations on this data, like returning derived information. This is one reason - employee information. Saving to the database is different reason concerning DAL and it does not concern the user of the Employee class. Reasons come from people: https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2014/05/08/SingleReponsibilityPrinciple.html